# Swift: Parsing data using .performSegue(withIdentifier: _, sender: self)

Tags: ios, swift

[Screenshot of ViewStudents and EditStudent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZKf3.png)

Hi, I'm trying to perform a segue from 'ViewStudents' to 'EditStudent' and wish to parse the id of the student to be edited.
As can be seen in the image I'm creating a new instance of 'EditStudent' and parsing the id. I think the issue I'm having is that I'm performing a segue to a different instance of 'EditStudent'.

Some tutorials say to use 'destination.performSegue(withIdentifier: "EditStudentSegue", sender: self)', but this returns an error notifying that the destination (e.g. EditStudent) has no segue member named "EditStudentSegue" which being that the segue is owned by 'ViewStudents'

If anyone can confirm this and help me navigate to the correct instance it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[Screenshot of ViewStudents and EditStudent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ee0rs.png)

Found the solution, just had to separate the preparatory statements in buttonTap(_:) for parsing data into the overriding prepare(for:sender:) function